# Issues granting access - Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics, users

I am the administrator of my company's Google Analytics account, but was recently asked to give a client access to their Google Analytics data.

Whilst I fully understand the new permissions structure Google has put in place, I've put the email address along with all the correct permissions but the client tells me they are being greated with a message stating that they "are unable to access Google Analytics because they don't have the correct levels of permission". I've granted them the right to Edit, Collaborate, Read & Analyze but they still have the same issue.

I am definitely using the client's correct email address and they're also using Gmail so that can't be the fault either.

Comment: You have to use the email address with which they sign into their Gmail accoint (ie their Gmail address).   You are inviting an @gmail.com address, right?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I've used the client's work email address and they are using Gmail for Business. As my company uses the exact same tool, this is adding even more confusion as to why this isn't working. Can you think of anything else it could be...?

Comment: I've invited others to see my Google Analytics data and it has worked for me.   This would be the type of problem that you would encounter if they are logging in with the wrong Google account.  You could try asking them for an alternate Google account and add that as well, just in case they are not logging in to the correct one.

Comment: Im beginning to think that this is what's causing the problem. I will ask for a new email address from them and, hopefully, this should sort the issue. Thanks for your help mate!

Comment: Never had that problem before.Try it out again by creating a new google account and then granting permissions.

Comment: I've closed this question, because the cause of this is not clear.  If you post more information, we can reopen it.